# Failed Creating App Engine Connected Android Project

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I am trying to create 'App Engine Connected Android Project' on Eclipse 4.2(Juno) but am facing 2 errors:

1) The first error shows up while creating new project:

```
Creation of Element Failed.
Reason:
Unknown protocol : d
```

And yet new project files are created in workspace under project's name.
I have installed latest Google plugin for Eclipse, ADT and Android Platform tools. 
I am not facing any problem while creating 'Android Application' project but while creating 'App Engine Connected Android Project' Eclipse is showing me this error.

2) I can see the newly created project files in workspace but there is one error in MainActivity.java file under src folder saying:
`RegisterActivity cannot be resolved to a type`

I am working on Win7 Professional 64bit and Eclipse 4.2(32bit).

Did I forget to install any plugins? What should I do?

Comment: A couple of questions. Can you check what version of GPE you have installed? Click on Help -> Installation Details -> Plugins, and sort by plugin id. Then, tell me what version numbers you see for the "com.google.gdt" and "com.google.appengine" plugins. Would you also be able to take a look at your error log (Window -> Show View -> Error Log) and see if there are more detailed messages there? Finally, is your default SDK set to App Engine 1.7.5? Thanks,
Rajeev

Comment: You might want to look into Google Cloud Endpoints.  The tutorial for App Engine Connected Android Project is pretty dated.

Comment: Do you have the latest App-Engine SDK? 1.7.5?
Preferences > Google > App Engine

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. What you can do is right-click on your android project, **Google > Generate AppEngine Backend**. The AppEngine project will automatically be created.

Then, on AppEngine project you can right click, **Google > Generate Cloud Endpoint Client Library** to create Endpoints. if you still get `RegisterActivity cannot be resolved to a type` error, please change your java compiler to 1.6.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but too long for a comment.

I see some comments above suggesting that user shouldn't be using "App Engine Connected Android Project".

That was my impression too, but now I'm not sure.  It is still prominent in the docs (with a last updated of February 14, 2013), it says nothing about being deprecated, and I found [a post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-plugin-eclipse/_op9guM5pf4/BArAH-d3TgEJ) from August saying that they only removed it temporarily and would be adding it back again (with GCM support).

It appears that they updated it for Endpoints and GCM, and it is still alive.  It is an alternative to creating a Android project and then using "Generate AppEngine Backend" wizard.